# How do I properly send the "this" object to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which I want to trigger on certain events. This function has to access the "this" object of the element that the event happened on. I am having hard time passing it to the function.

This is my code but it's not working, it looks like the problem is with the "thisVariable" not being the original element. I have similar code which is split into more functions but works, and I just wanted to simplify things.

```
$(document).on('focusin', '.formInput', function () {
    freezingScanNewRowEvaluation(this);
});

function freezingScanNewRowEvaluation(thisVariable) {
    var currentInput = thisVariable;
// other stuff, more event listeners binded to the original element
}
```

Should this aproach actually work and I am doing something else wrong, or is passing "this" like this nonsense? Thanks

Edit: My whole function: 
Edit2: The problem seems to be on binding more events to $(currentInput), it registers the Enter button, but nothing else is detected, and no errors show in console.

```
function freezingScanNewRowEvaluation(thisVariable) {
    var currentInput = thisVariable;
    var parentRow = thisVariable.closest(".formRow");
    var parentComponent = thisVariable.closest(".newScanRowComponent");
    var nextRow = $(parentRow).next();
    if ($(parentRow).hasClass("formRow--editMode") == false) {
        return;
}

$(parentRow).find("label").text($(".newScanRowComponent").length);

// Save current value of element
$(currentInput).data('oldVal', $(currentInput).val());

// Look for changes in the value
$(currentInput).bind("propertychange change click keyup input paste", function (event) {

    if (event.which == 13) {
       // stuff - This detects ok, but none of the other events do...
    }

    // If value has changed...
    var inputValueNew = $(currentInput).val();
    var inputValueOld = $(currentInput).data('oldVal');

    if (inputValueOld != inputValueNew) {
        // Updated stored value
       $(currentInput).data('oldVal', $(currentInput).val());

        if (inputValueNew.length - inputValueOld.length > 6) {
        rowSuccessMarkerShow(parentRow);
        switchInputRowType(parentRow);

        // stuff
        }   
    }
});

function switchInputRowType(row) {
    if ($(row).hasClass("formRow--editMode" && $(row).find("input").val() != "")) {
        // stuff
    } else if (row.hasClass("formRow--active")) {
        // stuff
    }
}

function rowSuccessMarkerShow(row) {
    if (!$(row).hasClass("formInput1") && $(row).find("input").val() != "") {
        // stuff
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: That looks like it should work, though you could simplify with `$(document).on('focusin', '.formInput', freezingScanNewRowEvaluation);` and then reference `this` inside `freezingScanNewRowEvaluation`

Comment: @CertainPerformance just as an allternative, use `freezingScanNewRowEvaluation.call(this)` or `freezingScanNewRowEvaluation.apply(this)`. That's assuming you want to do other stuff in the callback, otherwise I'd just remove the anonymous function like you did.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks guys, I must have something else wrong then...

Comment: Given that you describe that working code as non-working, I'd be interested in the `// other stuff`. Did you maybe try to use `currentInput.val()`, as opposed to `$(currentInput).val()`? (Or simply `$(thisVariable).val()`?) Example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/k7tcu3yw/

Comment: but what if ```this``` refers to ```.formInput``` but the actual element which triggered the event is deeper (event has been bubbled up).
You would then need to use ```...'.formInput', function (e) {freez..tion(e.target)}``` (I would expect .formInput to be a selector for an input but who knows...)

Comment: @ChrisG That was part of the problem, but I fixed it so no more errors appear in the console, but the function is still not working (not detecting events). I have it split into multiple separate functions which work fine...

Comment: @user753642 Interesting point, but the .formInput is the actual <input>, so how would the event be any deeper? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Please create a [mre]. Also, jQuery has a `closest()` function, so you shouldn't mix jQuery and vanilla JS like that unless unavoidable.

Comment: @PavelHoryna there are a lot of lines you can strip from your code. If you narrowed down the problem to: "some events won't do" just a console.log on that path is enough.
Also you have not provided the DOM so refer to Chris G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the replies, you were all most helpful!

The most important things I needed to ask I learned from the first two replies by CertainPerformance and VLAZ. 
It appears that my error was that I put brackets behind the callback function here:
$(document).on('focusin', '.formInput', freezingScanNewRowEvaluation**()**);
After removing them it now works fine.

Thanks again!